# Communicating with USB port

Tags: java, usb

I'm working on a project for school and got stuck.
My problem is that I have no idea *how to communicate with the USB port* to control my ATmega8. I'm trying to control the electricity in a miniature house.
My IC is ready, I can control it with switches.

I will have a UI on my PC in which I can switch on/off lights, open garage door end gate. I *need to send a number* (unique for every button) from PC to IC through USB.

Edit:
I'm connecting to pins 18 and 19 (pins 4 and 5 of B port).
I want to send the number bit by bit in serial mode and *would like to use one of the data cables(ex: DATA+) for clock and the other one (ex: DATA-) as data.*
My Atmega is ready to process this kind of transmission, it's working fine when I'm imputing a number serially using switches.

Edit:
I downloaded **jna.jar** and **platform.jar** from [this link](http://www.blog.kslemb.com/doku.php/en/projects/globx/java_hid). If those are the good files, could someone also do a step by step explanation on where to put and how to use downloaded libraries.

Comment: Try taking a look at [javahidapi](http://code.google.com/p/javahidapi/), or just search for a Java "usbhid" library you like.

Comment: What USB class is the ATmega presenting? Are you using an external USB chip or bit-banging the USB stack on the microcontroller?

Comment: I found this [link](http://www.blog.kslemb.com/doku.php/en/projects/globx/java_hid). But I don't know were to put the jna.jar and platform.jar files. I'm using NetBeans IDE 7.4.

Comment: @chrylis I'm connecting directly to the ATmega

Comment: How is the ATmega configured? There's no built-in USB support in the ATmega8.

Answer (score 0):

you can get some useful help [here](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/07/06/java-and-usb.html)